# How to add indentation in Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a column in excel which I have written using Xssfworkbook and the column width is 10. The data in that column is "I need more data related to them".
But I will be able to see only the last 10 letters in that column unless I click on it "ed to them".

I don't want to wrap text or increase the column width. It's fine for me if the data shows up even in the next column. Can please someone help me, I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Can you please share code and properly explain what you want to achieve

Comment: I have a cell where the value is present but the value is not visible properly. I want it to be visible without wrap text or increasing the column width

Comment: I found a posting https://superuser.com/a/1056915 that explains the conditions necessary for text from one cell to overflow into the adjacent cell that I think addresses your question

Comment: So how do you expect the cell to look like? No wrap, no column-width extension, so this only leaves using a smaller font, or?

Comment: This is how I want my cell to look like..

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1056915.  I need how can this be achieved using java

Answer (score 0):

Not able to get want you want to achieve but you can use

`autoSizeColumn(columnNumber)` to auto fit the contents

Here is a [link](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFSheet.html#autoSizeColumn%28int%29) for explanation

Comment: I don't want to autosize columns. You can just try to open an excel and write a text which is greater than the column width. The data shows up clearly.. that is what I want to achieve using poi

Comment: This is what I want to achieve using java https://superuser.com/a/1056915

Comment: I don't have any piece of working code for it. I m trying many trial and error for it.. but couldn't achieve it

Comment: Please share at least non working code and share image what you are getting and what you want to get